# Maven precedence : "initialize" phase vs property initialization

Tags: maven

I have an "argLine" initialization occurring through jacoco "prepare-agent" goal bound to "initialize" phase.

I have an "argLine" initialization occuring through property declaration in a maven profile declaration.

How can I know which one is occuring first and which one needs to concatenate to the other ?

Comment: Can you please show your pom file... usually you don't need to set them manually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profiles are merged and properties are set before any phase runs.